# Child script causes main script to exit?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, exit-code

I see very odd behaviour in bash, and Im trying to understand what is happening.

I have a main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

DEBUG="N"

source child.sh

echo "Returned"
```

and a child script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

[ "$DEBUG" = "Y" ] && echo && echo "Finished.." && echo
```

When DEBUG is Y the main script continues to run just fine. But when DEBUG is N the main script just exits there without any error message, and the "Returned" line is never reached.

When I put an extra dummy line at the end, so that it becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

[ "$DEBUG" = "Y" ] && echo && echo "Finished.." && echo
echo "" > /dev/null
```

The script behaves correctly again in both cases.

But I cannot figure out why I need that dummy line. I am sure the solution must be very simple.

Comment: Why should there be an error message? The condition isn't true, so it doesn't execute the `echo` commands after it. Since it's the last line of the script, there's nothing else for the script to do, so it exits.

Comment: Your script returns has a non-0 exit status when that line is the last line that's executed and `$DEBUG` is not `Y`, because `test` (or `[` or its built-in equivalent) has exited with a non-0 status.

Comment: Oh, you mean the original script that sourced it.

Comment: @Barmar This script is called from another script using `source`, I mentioned that in the question. So I mean the main script doesnt continue its executing after that.

Comment: Do you have `set -e` in the original script?

Comment: Please try to provide a [mre].

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, that must be the problem. If you post your comment as the answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Maestro: I'm just wildly guessing and I'm not confident enough in my bash-foo to speak authoritatively about it. But if it ends up helping you, feel free to post a self-answer describing what you had to change, those are very much welcome here.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes... I think Joachim is right that the exit code needs to be cleared.. but I dont know how to do that, because "exit 0" or "return" will also end the main script. And to include an unrelated dummy line feels stupid.

Comment: Slight rephrase of the question: "How does `set -e` work in conjunction with `source` and short-circuiting boolean operators?"  Answer "No one really knows, and it's different with every version of bash"  see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when DEBUG is N the main script just exits there without any error message.
>
> Do you have set -e in the original script?
>
> @Barmar Yes.... –  Maestro

The script exit status is the exit status of the last command executed.

When `[ "$DEBUG" = "Y" ]` is false, it exits with non-zero exit status.

So the command list `[ "$DEBUG" = "Y" ] && echo && echo "Finished.." && echo` exits with non-zero exit status.

So your child script exits with non-zero exit status.

Because your "main script" has `set -e`, it detects that a command exited with non-zero exit status and terminuates.

Use `trap ... ERR` to make `set -e` visible. Do not use `&&` if you mean `if`. Prefer:

```
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "Y" ]]; then
   echo
   echo "Finished.."
   echo
fi
```

The exit status of `if` when the expression has non-zero exit status, is zero. But note, that the exit status of `if` when the expression is true, is the exit status of the last command executed - in this case it will be the third `echo`, which we expect to exit with zero.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the exitcode (like exit 0 does in a non-sourced script). So that I can put that as the last line in all my child scripts?

Comment: You can `return` from sourced script. `that I can put that` Do not use set -e if you don't want it. It has many corner cases you have to understand. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 . If you want `set -e`, write proper scripts - use `if` instead of `&&` `||`.

Comment: I already tried `return` and it did not work. Turned out you need to do `return 0` explicitly to make it work.

Comment: `return` without a value returns the exit status of the last command executed, in other words `return` is `return $?`. See `help return`